# Many-to-many relationship: how to delete records from 3 table?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

For example, I have the following tables:

```
person          person_address            address
==========      ==================        ===========
pid   (PK)      pid           (FK)        aid    (PK)
...             aid           (FK)        ...
```

I've set `pid` to `ON DELETE CASCADE` and `aid` to `ON DELETE NO ACTION`. The goal is to delete the according record from `address` if a `person` gets deleted.

I have tried trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER pa_delete 
AFTER DELETE ON person_address
FOR EACH ROW 
DELETE FROM address
WHERE person_address.address_id = address.address_id
```

But when I delete the `person` record, `address` record is still there. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

---

Tables involved:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chkdcrm`.`person` (
  `person_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `tel` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `fax` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `mobile` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `email` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chkdcrm`.`address` (
  `address_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` ENUM('Invoice', 'Shipping', 'Site', 'Mailing') NOT NULL,
  `street` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `zip` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `country` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chkdcrm`.`person_address` (
  `address_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `person_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`, `person_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pa_address`
    FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`)
    REFERENCES `chkdcrm`.`address` (`address_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pa_person`
    FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`)
    REFERENCES `chkdcrm`.`person` (`person_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Check the table engine if it is MyISAM the `ON CASCADE` doesnt not work it needs to be InnoDB engine.

Comment: @RaymondNijland i am using innodb

Comment: Provide de `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` statements for all tables involved..

Comment: @RaymondNijland code is provided. Care to take another look?

Comment: logical InnoDB doesn't delete the other records when you delete from the table person.. You need to delete from person_adress because there you are using the references... `DELETE * FROM person_address WHERE person_id = id`  should also delete the records from person because of the delete casade.. ..

Comment: Since person_address get deleted with person (because of cascade), wouldn't it activate the trigger ?